# Prevent application from changing desktop resolution

Tags: c#

So i have a really old game client that annoyingly takes it upon itself to change the desktop resolution to cater for something like 1600x900 resolution to achieve full screen, i'm trying to figure out how to stop this happening.

I imagine it's calling something like ChangeDisplaySettings() in user32.dll, if so is it possible to block specific dll calls, or perhaps an easier way?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I should add the game client is not my own thus i have no direct control over what it's doing.

I have managed to breakpoint before the ChangeDisplaySettingsA() call and modify the lpDevMode parameters to achieve what i want, now i just need to figure out how to do this programmatically.

Comment: Would it be hard to change your game according to the resolution? I would rather focus on how to fix the problem instead of how to block certain resolutions.

Comment: Check Microsoft Detour but honestly I'd simply disassemble and change code where it calls that function (be aware I do not think this is *legal*)

Comment: Mind pointing me in the right direction to disassemble and change the appropriate function call? I have the client open in IDA but its new to me